# mat-checkbox inside nested mat-table does not change state

Tags: angular

I have a `mat-table` that displays a list of users. Each row is expandable and opens when it is clicked, revealing a nested `mat-table`. The nested table displays a role matrix and I want each role to be turned on/off with a `mat-checkbox`. The problem I am facing is that the `mat-checkbox` is clickable (that is, I can see the material design visual feedback that it was clicked - animated red flash), but the checkbox state doesn't change. I also don't see the `(change)="roleSet($event)` doing anything, the method isn't called.

If I place this `mat-checkbox` outside of the nested table, the `roleSet` method gets called, so obviously something is messed up here.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="sortableDataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort
         class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.value}}" *ngFor="let column of tableHeaders">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.displayName}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.value]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="tableHeaders.length">
        <div class="example-element-detail"
             [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">

          <!-- Inner role table-->
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="getRoleMatrixRows(element.roles)">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of getRoleColumns(element.roles)">

              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

                <mat-checkbox (change)="roleSet($event)"></mat-checkbox>

              </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getRoleColumns(element.roles)"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getRoleColumns(element.roles);"></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableValues()"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: tableValues();"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
        (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
    </tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>

    <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
    <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No search results found for "{{input.value}}"</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the click event from propagating up to expand / contract the row when checkbox is clicked.  So:

This bit:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <mat-checkbox (change)="roleSet($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

Needs this added:  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"

To become:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <mat-checkbox (change)="roleSet($event)"></mat-checkbox>
</td>
```